# R: Creating animated xy graph with png background using saveVideo() and rasterImage (too slow)

Tags: r, animation, plot

I am have a dataframe with time, `t` and `x`,`y` coordinates of a person walking on a known map of `x:0-520` , `y:0-300`. I would like to create an animation of the person walking at each `t` with a background of the plot being the map.

I tried using `saveVideo()` from the animation package, without the background first and it worked well. When I try adding the background using `rasterImage()`, it takes up too much time to plot the PNG in the background as it plots the PNG from scratch during each loop.

Is there a way that I could speed up this process by not having `rasterImage()` to run on every loop?

Is it possible to remove a plotted point, and plot a new point so I do not have to run `rasterImage()` again?

Your help will be greatly appreciated!

Below is my code:
a is the dataframe with `x`,`y`,`t` as columns

```
saveVideo({ 
ani.options(interval = 1/100, nmax = 50)
xy = a[,1:2]
t = a$t
ima <- readPNG("floorplan.png")
for (i in 600:800) {
    plot(xy[i,], xlim = c(0,520),ylim = c(0,300))

    ####to plot my png as background. works fine if this section is omitted
    lim <- par()
    rasterImage(ima, lim\$usr[1], lim\$usr[3], lim\$usr[2], lim\$usr[4])
    #####


    legend('topright',legend=paste('time =',i), bty='n')
    ani.pause()
    }
},movie.name = "pathBG.mp4")
```

Answer (score 1):

Since R is mainly a *statistical* tool and not a bare-metal programming language it does not have a lot of support for high performance graphics out-of-the box.

To improve the performance of generating your animation your best bet is to use the [RGL](http://rgl.neoscientists.org/about.shtml) package. This allows you to use the graphics hardware of your machine for displaying graphics. You can set-up your RGL scene once and then reuse it to make all the snapshots you need for your animation, so no long loading times!

Here are the steps to take:

1. **Install the RGL package**
2. **Setup your scene** with either your PNG as background, or as a material on a box object. Position your walking person.
3. **Take a snapshot** of the scene and save the png
4. **Move your walking person** position
5. **Repeat** from step 3.

For a code example see the excellent post from Guillaume Fillion, [here](http://www.genomearchitecture.com/2014/03/3d-animations-with-r)